# C++ comma weird behavior with numbers

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a simplest possible code which has to accept and reprint two numbers. It works well for any separating symbol I've tried (space, + ,etc.) except (!) the comma.

```
cout << "Enter x & y coordinates: ";
cin >> x;
cin >> y;
cout << "Coordinates are (" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
```

- 2 2 outputs (2,2)
- 2+2 outputs (2,2)
- 2.2 waits for the second number

but 2,2 **doesn't** prompt for a second number and just outputs (2,0).
Why is this happening? Where does the stuff after the comma go?

Comment: What's the type of `x` and `y`?

Comment: @Quentin my mistake, both are double.

Answer (score 3):

> It works well for any separating symbol I've tried (space, + ,etc.) except (!) the comma.

In fact, no.

- spaces (including tab, eol) are indeed ignored.
- `2+2` are 2 numbers: `2` and `+2` (as number can begin with `+` or `-`)

In other cases, `std::cin >> y` would fail, and set `cin` in error state, and set y to 0.

Comment: So setting the input target to 0 is the C++ way of handling input errors? Sounds inconvenient :/

Comment: No, you have to test `std::cin` for error. setting to 0 avoid UB in case of error for usage as your (you would print uninitialized variable).